# ArcGIS Pro SDK forcing process windows to be minimized?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, c#, arcgis-pro-sdk

I'm running a Process from my add-in, and even if I use P/Invoke to force the window to be open and in the foreground, the process windows that appear will be minimized. Weirdly enough, they are minimized only when using the installed version of the add-in. If I'm debugging in VS, process windows are never minimized, and always get focus.

I start the Process as one normally would,

```
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(fileName, arguments)
{
    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
};
var process = Process.Start(startInfo);

// Here I would put my P/Invoke method calls to try to force-show the window,
// which of course didn't end up working

process?.WaitForExit();
```

And despite this, the windows from the process will appear, and then quickly become minimized. I've attempted to use P/Invoke methods like `ShowWindow()`, `ShowWindowAsync()`, `setForegroundWindow()`, with `process.MainWindowHandle` and nothing fixes the issue. I've tried `process.WaitForInputIdle()` before showing the window to ensure the window has been created before I attempt to show it, but this doesn't work either. It's as if Arc is forcefully minimizing the windows. I've also tried to obtain a `Control` from the `MainWindowHandle`, but it always comes out null. It's bizarre that there is no issue when running Arc with a Debug configuration in VS, it's only when I use the add-in as a typical user would.

How can I stop ArcGIS Pro from minimizing the process windows?

Comment: You may have better luck asking this question on the esri geonet forum as it requires a deep understanding of the ArcPro application?